# Arrange text in the ComboBox

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I try to create some correct XAML **to arrange text in the `ComboBox` to the right**, but I cannot.

Here is my XAMl... 
Any clue what I am missing? 
Thank you!

```
 <ComboBox Height="25"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding NonArchivedSequences}"  
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSequence}"
           Margin="0,0,0,4" 
           Name="cbSequences" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="504"                   
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
           SelectionChanged="cbSequences_SelectionChanged"
           Grid.Column="1">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateSequenceData">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="4,2,2,4"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Text="{Binding Interval}" 
                                   d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="4,2,2,4"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Column="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataTemplateSequenceData"/>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe HorizonalAllignment="Right"  You have Left

Comment: Hi! Where do I have to put it?

Comment: Where you have HorizonalAllignment="Left"

Comment: I did this <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"> and it works. Thanks man!!